# GAE User registry without Google Accounts, want to restric to specific domain

Tags: python, google-app-engine, web-applications

I am planning on creating an application for the students of my school, and I want to restrict user registration to emails of the form person@myschool.edu. I would prefer to not manually create the user table and do the password hashing and such. Are there any libraries you can recommend for this?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you tell us how your school's user accounts are managed? Is it using Active Directory? Or maybe Google Apps for Education? Because you would need to have some kind of link between that and your App Engine app to handle the login process. If we know what you're using, someone can suggest a relevant solution.

Comment: I don't know how the user accounts are managed. Couldn't I just have a regexp or something that only allows certain emails to register?

Comment: yes, you could just filter the email address to just allow the domain you want, but then you still would need to do all the user management (create and manage passwords, etc.) which I believe from your question is not what you want to do?

Comment: You are correct. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: then you would need to find out how the user accounts are managed, because you would need some kind of link between your app and the school's user account system. Ideally you want to pass the login details entered in your app through to their system (in a secure way) and get some confirmation back if it is a valid user.
Just curious: are you affiliated with the school's IT department, or just a student who wants to create an app for your fellow students? Because if it's the latter it would probably be quite hard to get the IT dept to cooperate with your project.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes, if you just send the user to a login screen you will end in a redirect loop if the user is already logged with a Google Account.
What i have found to be a good answer to this problem is to redirect the user to a log out page so he can later login with the domain you want.

I have used this for my code

```
user = users.get_current_user()

#Check if the user is in @mydomain.com

if user:
    emailDomain = user.email().split("@")
    if emailDomain[1] == "mydomain.com":
        return True
    else:
        self.redirect(users.create_logout_url('/startPage'))
else:
    self.redirect(users.create_login_url(self.request.uri))
```

This way, the application logs you out automatically and asks for your domain credentials

Answer (score 0):

Since you said you don't know how the email are registered, that you don't want to manage a login/password database and you just need a regexp or somethings (I quote here!), I assume you could keep it very simple.
Something like.

```
user = users.get_current_user()
  if user:
    emailDomain = user.email().split("@")
    if emailDomain == "yourschool.edu":
      doSomething()
```

That way, all the trouble of registering to your app is given to the users (who will need to get a Google Account).